# replacing old line voltage thermostat

Tags: thermostat

My old 4 wire 240V mechanical line voltage thermostat stopped working. I want to replace it with a digital thermostat. Problem is I don't know the amp rating of the old thermostat. I checked with maker and they have no info...too old. Is there a way to check amp rating of old thermostat? A very good electrician installed the two 8 foot baseboard heaters, thermostat, 2-pole 20 amp circuit breaker and all wiring about 25 years but he is nolonger around.

Comment: Your options of smart stat will be limited.  How do you feel about a significantly more complex install, but that will open you up to pretty much all the popular smart 'stats such as Nest?

Comment: I found the label on the heaters. 2000/1504 amps 240/208V. Based on amp calcs I found online they showed watts/volts=amps. I have two heaters so total watts = 4,000. So 4,000 /240=16.6667. So wouldn't a 16.7 amp stat work?

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the old 'stat?

Comment: That is the problem...the only markings on the old Berko stat are on the bi-metal tab (H00D 36-10) and the manufacturer told me they have no info...to old.

Comment: The two heaters - watts 4,000. So 4,000 /240=16.6667. So would a 16.7 amp stat work?

Comment: I think you have to subtract 25 percent to get the max load on the circuit

Comment: I recently researched replacing my Line voltage thermostat, there are many digital and programmable options but  i found there is really only one smart option available.  https://www.amazon.com/Mysa-Thermostat-Electric-Baseboard-Heaters/dp/B075VBP42M/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1N6VHW3QTSMYW&dchild=1&keywords=line+voltage+thermostat&qid=1608847783&sprefix=line+volt%2Caps%2C295&sr=8-3

Comment: How to Tell the Wattage of Electric Baseboard Heaters -  https://help.getmysa.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026051511-How-can-I-calculate-the-total-wattage-connected-to-one-thermostat-  https://homeguides.sfgate.com/tell-wattage-electric-baseboard-heaters-25864.html

Answer (score 2):

20 amp circuit, so 20 amps (or more, but not less) for the thermostat.